# Replace the last alphanumeric with a random char of same type

Tags: shell, text-processing, random

I have a simple list of alphanumeric machine names in a file, and I want to change the last letter or number, but I want it to match character type -- so if the last character is a digit, it should be replaced with a random digit; if the last character is a letter, it should be replaced with a random letter:

```
bob1234
pittsburgh
0091919
```

Would become:

```
bob1239
pittsburgp
0091915
```

Comment: And the question is? And what you try?

Comment: How random should the replacement letter/digit be? is it acceptable if someone could eg deduct from `4->9` and `h->p` that a `9` on the next line will be replaced by a `5`?

Comment: Could `o` be replaced with `ë`, or must it be strict US ASCII? Now, same question, but with the characters swapped?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
awk '
  BEGIN{
    srand()
    letter = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    digit  = "0123456789"
  }
  function find_in(set) {
    if (index(set, c)) {
      c = substr(set, int(rand() * length(set) + 1), 1)
      return 1
    }
  }
  $0 != "" {
    c = substr($0, length)
    if (find_in(letter) || find_in(digit)) sub(/.$/, c)
  }
  {print}'
```

Note that with most `awk` implementations, if you run those commands twice in the same second, you'll get the same result as the seed for the pseudo-random generator is based on the current time in seconds.

The replacement character is random which means it could be the same as the original. If you want to exclude the original from the list of possible replacements, you could change the `find_in` function to:

```
  function find_in(set,   n) {
    if (n = index(set, c)) {
      set = substr(set, 1, n - 1) substr(set, n + 1)
      c = substr(set, int(rand() * length(set) + 1), 1)
      return 1
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the perl [String::Random](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::Random) module:

```
perl -MString::Random -pe '
  BEGIN{$s = String::Random->new} 
  s{[a-z0-9]$}{$s->randpattern($& =~ /\d/ ? "n" : "c")}e
' file
```

Note that this does not exclude the replacement character being the same as the original. A possibly inefficient and ugly way to fix that might be to just "roll the die" until a different character is generated:

```
perl -MString::Random -pe '
  BEGIN{$s = String::Random->new} 
  s{[a-z0-9]$}{do {$c = $s->randpattern($& =~ /\d/ ? "n" : "c")} until $c ne $&; $c}e
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Pure `bash` method:

   ```
   printf -v s '%s' {a..z} {A..Z} {0..9}
   while read x; do  
       n=${x:((-1))}
       echo -n ${x%?} 
       p=${s#*$n}
       echo ${s:(( (${#p}>=10) ? RANDOM*52/32768 : 52 + RANDOM*10/32768 )):1}
   done < file
   ```
2. *GNU* `sed` method, using the ***`e`****valuate* command to run `tr` and `head` on */dev/urandom* to generate random chars:

   ```
   sed 's/\(.*\)\(.\)$/\
          printf \1 ; \
          echo \2 | \
          tr '[:alpha:][:digit:]' "$({ tr -dc '[:alpha:]' | head -c 52; \
                                       tr -dc '[:digit:]' | head -c 10; \
                                      } < \/dev\/urandom;)"/e'  file
   ```

Output (varies between runs):

```
bob1237
pittsburgq
0091916
```

---

Note: neither method checks if the randomly selected char is different from the previous char, but it most usually would be.